# File transfer in group chat with XMPP

Tags: xmpp, file-transfer, openfire, smack, asmack

I am using group chat with open fire.

i can able to send messages but how to send file to group with Smack library.

i can able to send file to single user with below but i don't know how  to send to group chat (MUC) so all users in room will receive that file

```
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("usre2@myHost/Smack");
```

Comment: do you find any solution for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Use [XEP-0066: Out of Band Data](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0066.html) - this is small extension to standard groupchat message  with url and description. Other users will receive link to the file. Smack library does not have standard implementation, but it is very simple.

Comment: hey vitalyster need help in this XEP-0066.. i m client side guy.. how can i implement this..i want to implement file transfer in muc. i'm using asmack as client side.