# Xmpp OutgoingFileTransfer stopps with Status= Refused

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I try to send a File via xmpp and smack

```
FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(
            this.xmppConnection);
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager
            .createOutgoingFileTransfer(this.jid);

transfer.sendFile(file, "test");

while (!transfer.isDone()) {

LOGGER.info("Uploading File: " + file.getName() + "   STATUS: "
    + transfer.getStatus() + "  >> progress: " + 100
    * transfer.getProgress());
try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception: " + ex);
    }
}

LOGGER.info("File transfer is done: " + file.getName() + "   STATUS: "
    + transfer.getStatus() + "  >> progress: " + 100
    * transfer.getProgress());
LOGGER.info("Amount written: " + transfer.getAmountWritten());
LOGGER.info("Bytes sent: " + transfer.getBytesSent());
LOGGER.info("Peer: " + transfer.getPeer());
LOGGER.info("Error: " + transfer.getError());
LOGGER.info("Exception: ", transfer.getException());
```

The logs are:
    Uploading File: image_P9.png   STATUS: Initial  >> progress: 0.0
    Uploading File: image_P9.png   STATUS: Negotiating Transfer  >> progress: 0.0
    File transfer is done: image_P9.png   STATUS: Refused  >> progress: 0.0
    Amount written: -1
    Bytes sent: -1
    Peer: felix.infraview@jabber.de/IM+ Android
    Error: null
    Exception:

so I don't get a Error or Exception. The sending is just refused.

My goal is to send an inline-image to any android client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> STATUS: Refused
>
> ...
>
> Peer: felix.infraview@jabber.de/IM+

It means the target peer does not support file transfer methods you offer to. [XMPP SI File Transfer](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html) is a very complex specification which is not implemented by simple clients.
In fact, it does not properly implemented in Smack too, they can give you detailed description about error, but implemented only generic "refused".

Comment: Could you give me a roadmap what i have to do to send the file? The Goal is to send a inline-image to any android client.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344806/file-transfer-in-group-chat-with-xmpp

Comment: Also you can find my XEP-0066 Smack extension here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372589/create-message-while-sending-image-through-asmack